# How do I get the dynamic elements value?

Tags: forms

I wrote code to display fields, but I can't get all the entered values.

```
function payroll_emp_form($form, &$form_submit) {
    for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++) {
     $form['foo_fieldset']['row_' . $i] = array(
       '#prefix' => '<tr>',
       '#suffix' => '</tr>',
     );
     $form['foo_fieldset']['row_' . $i]['names'] = array(
       '#markup' => $query_emp_result1->name,
       '#prefix' => '<td>',
       '#suffix' => '</td>',
     );

     $form['foo_fieldset']['row_' . $i]['accountno'] = array(
       '#type' => 'markup',
       '#markup' => $query_emp_result1->account_no,
       '#prefix' => '<td>',
       '#suffix' => '</td>',
     );

     $form['foo_fieldset']['row_' . $i]['perdaypay'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#maxlength' =>2, 
      '#size' => 10,
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#prefix' => '<td>',
      '#suffix' => '</td>',
    );
  }

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#submit' => array('payroll_emp_form_submit'),
  );
  return $form;
}

function payroll_emp_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $accountno = $form_state['values']['foo_fieldset']['row_' . $a]['accountno'];
  $perdaypay = $form_state['values']['foo_fieldset']['row_' . $a]['perdaypay'];
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Without using `'#tree'` and setting it to `TRUE`, `$form_state['values']` will just contain `$form_state['values']['perdaypay']`. `$form_state['values']` just contains the values submitted from the user; it doesn't contain markup as you expect.

To correct the first error, the code needs to be similar to the following one.

```
function payroll_emp_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['foo_fieldset'] = array(
    '#tree' => TRUE,
  );

  for ($i=1; $i<=2; $i++) {
    $form['foo_fieldset']["row_$i"] = array(
      '#prefix' => '<tr>',
      '#suffix' => '</tr>',
    );

    $form['foo_fieldset']["row_$i"]['names'] = array(
      '#markup' => $query_emp_result1->name,
      '#prefix' => '<td>',
      '#suffix' => '</td>',
    );

    $form['foo_fieldset']["row_$i"]['accountno'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $query_emp_result1->account_no,
      '#prefix' => '<td>',
      '#suffix' => '</td>',
    );

    $form['foo_fieldset']["row_$i"]['perdaypay'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#maxlength' =>2, 
     '#size' => 10,
     '#required' => TRUE,
     '#prefix' => '<td>',
     '#suffix' => '</td>',
   );
 }

 $form['submit'] = array(
   '#value' => 'Submit',
   '#type' => 'submit',
   '#submit' => array('payroll_emp_form_submit'),
 );

 return $form;
}

function payroll_emp_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  for ($i=1; $i<=2; $i++) {
    $perdaypay = $form_state['values']['foo_fieldset']["row_$i"]['perdaypay'];
    // Use $perdaypay.
  }  
}
```

If then you wanted to be able to access `$form_state['values']['foo_fieldset']["row_$i"]['accountno']`, you should use the following, in the form.

```
 $form['foo_fieldset']["row_$i"]['accountno'] = array(
   '#type' => 'hidden',
   '#value' => $query_emp_result1->account_no;
   '#prefix' => "<td>{$query_emp_result1->account_no}",
   '#suffix' => '</td>',
 );
```